# How do I properly define the Entry Model for Django admin site?

Tags: django, model, admin

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
 
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

When I updated models.py, the makemigrations command returned a traceback. I also updated the admin.py file adding admin.site.register(Entry). The same traceback showed and I have been stuck on this problem. Please help to find a solution.

Comment: Please share the full traceback...

Comment: topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: Im not sure how to share full traceback. So many tracebacks for the previous model.py problem.

Comment: I see the edit now. Thanks for your help Willem!